# Is there any better approach on this rows to columns table?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I pass a function into the variable ($monthly_receivable) to get the value of each months to pass and get the result of a function.. but the process is dumb slow. This was the only january data but it can add a distance months example January 2016 to December 2019.

When i try to remove that variable monthly_receivable it was smooth.

This is my code from server-side to view (client-side):

**Controller**

```
public function notes_receivable_summary($start_date, $end_date) {
    $loans_list = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                                    borr_name,
                                        co_borrower, 
                                        released_date, 
                                        due_from, 
                                        due_to, 
                                        pn, 
                                        no_months, 
                                        loan_ref, 
                                        loan_id, 
                                        pn 
                                    FROM v_borrowers_nr dd
                                    WHERE (df between '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
                                    ORDER BY loan_ref")->result();
    $months     = $this->db->query("SELECT dd FROM v_months_nr WHERE dd between '$start_date' and '$end_date'")->result();

    $data['monthly_receivable'] = function($date, $loan_ref, $loan_id){
            $enc_url = explode('|', $this->Main_model->encdec($this->uri->segment(2), 'd'));
            $s_date  = $enc_url[1];
            $e_date  = $enc_url[2];
            $sd      = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 months', strtotime($s_date)));
            $ed      = $e_date;

      $q             = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM f_monthly_rcvble('$loan_ref', $loan_id, '$start_date', '$end_date', '$date')")->row();
        return $q;
    };
    $this->load->view('pages/ajax/reports/sample_nr', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<table id="displayTableNR" class="table displayTableNR js-sort-table">
  <?php $month = array(1=>'Jan', 2=>'Feb', 3=>'Mar', 4=>'Apr', 5=>'May', 6=>'Jun', 7=>'Jul', 8=>'Aug', 9=>'Sep', 10=>'Oct', 11=>'Nov', 12=>'Dec'); ?>
  <?php $total_as_of_h = 0; ?>
  <?php $range_date    = !empty($months) ? date('M Y', strtotime($months[0]->dd)) . ' - ' . date('M Y', strtotime($months[count($months) - 1]->dd)) : null; ?>
  <thead>
      <tr class="menu1">
          <th class="table-head b-right" scope="col">Ref. No.</th>
          <th class="table-head b-right js-sort-string fixed-side" scope="col">Name</th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side" scope="col">Co-Borrower</th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side" scope="col"><div class="wd-132px">Release Date</div></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right js-sort-date fixed-side" scope="col">From</th>
          <th class="table-head b-right js-sort-date fixed-side" scope="col">To</th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side text-right" scope="col">PN</th>
          <th class="table-head fixed-side" scope="col">Terms</th>

          <?php $count = 0; ?>
          <?php foreach ($months as $row): ?>
              <?php $d = explode('-', $row->dd); ?>
              <th class="table-head text-center font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 === 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>" colspan="10"><?php echo strtoupper($month[(int) $d[1]]) . ' ' . $d[0]; ?></th>
          <?php $count++; ?>
          <?php $total_as_of_h++; ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          <?php if ($total_as_of_h === count($months)): ?>
              <th class="td-head text-center" colspan="3">COLLECTION ACTUAL/CLOSED OB/EFP</th>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
      <tr class="menu2">
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side"></th>
          <th class="table-head fixed-side"></th>

          <?php $count = 0; ?>
          <?php foreach ($months as $row): ?>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 === 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Current Target</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong amt_pd <?php echo $count % 2 === 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Actual Collection</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">UA/SP</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Past Due Target UA/SP</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Actual Collection UA/SP</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Past Due Balance UA/SP</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Advanced Payment</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">OB Closed</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Early Full Payments</div></th>
              <th class="table-head font-strong <?php echo $count % 2 == 0 ? 'hexa-color-1' : 'hexa-color-2'; ?>"><div class="wd-132px text-center">Adjustments</div></th>
          <?php $count++; ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          <?php if ($total_as_of_h === count($months)): ?>
              <th class="table-head">TOTAL</th>
              <th class="table-head"><div class="wd-118px text-center">(<?php echo $range_date; ?>)</div></th>
              <th class="table-head">NR BAL</th>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <?php $totAmntToPay             = 0; ?>            
  <?php $totCollection            = 0; ?>            
  <?php $totBalance               = 0; ?>            

  <?php foreach($loans_list as $r): ?>
  <?php $name   = explode('|', $r->borr_name); ?>
  <tr class="">
    <td class="td-border fixed-side"><?php echo $r->loan_ref; ?></td>
    <?php if (count($name) < 3): ?>
      <td class="td-border br-name-nr fixed-side"><div class="wd-210px"><?php echo strtoupper($name[0]) . ', ' . strtoupper($name[1]); ?></div></td>
    <?php else: ?>
      <td class="td-border br-name-nr fixed-side"><div class="wd-210px"><?php echo strtoupper($name[0]) . ', ' . strtoupper($name[1]) . ' ' . strtoupper($name[2]); ?></div></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="td-border fixed-side"><div class="wd-145px"><?php echo strtoupper($r->co_borrower); ?></div></td>
    <td class="td-border fixed-side"><?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($r->released_date)); ?></td>
    <td class="td-border fixed-side"><?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($r->due_from)); ?></td>
    <td class="td-border fixed-side"><?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($r->due_to)); ?></td>
    <td class="td-border text-right fixed-side"><?php echo number_format($r->pn, 2); ?></td>
    <td class="td-border fixed-side"><?php echo number_format($r->no_months, 0); ?></td>

    <!-- TOTALS VARIABLE -->
    <?php $ct1                   = 0; ?>
    <?php $curr_or_prev_uasp     = 0; ?>
    <?php $tot_prev_uasp_balance = 0; ?>

    <?php foreach($months as $row): ?>
    <?php $lref = $r->loan_ref; ?>
    <?php $lid  = $r->loan_id; ?>
    <?php $nr                     = $monthly_receivable($row->dd, $lref, $lid); ?>
      <?php if (is_object($nr)): ?>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->amount_due, 2); ?></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->actual_collection, 2); ?></td>
          <?php if ($ct1 == 0): ?>
            <td class="td-border text-right"></td>
          <?php else: ?>  
            <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->col_ua_sp, 2); ?></td>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->past_due_target_ua_sp, 2); //Past Due Target UA/SP ?></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><a href="#" class="clrd-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title=""><?php echo number_format($nr->past_due_collection_tot_ua_sp, 2); ?></a></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->past_due_balance, 2); //Past Due Target Balance ?></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><a href="#" class="clrd-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title=""><?php echo number_format($nr->advanced_payment, 2); ?></a></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->ob_closed, 2); ?></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->early_full_payments, 2); ?></td>
        <td class="td-border text-right"><?php echo number_format($nr->adjustments, 2); ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- TOTALS -->
    <?php $ct1++; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <td class="td-border text-right total-to-pay"><?php echo number_format($col_tot_pn, 2); ?></td>
    <td class="td-border text-right total-coll"><?php echo number_format($col_tot_col, 2); ?></td>
    <td class="td-border text-right total-bal"><?php echo number_format($col_tot_pn - $col_tot_col, 2); ?></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side">Ref. No.</th>
        <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side">Name</th>
        <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side">Co-Borrower</th>
        <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side">Release Date</th>
        <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side">From</th>
        <th class="table-head b-right fixed-side">To</th>
        <th class="table-head b-right text-right fixed-side"><?php echo number_format($totPN, 2); ?></th>
        <th class="table-head fixed-side">Terms</th>

        <?php if ($total_as_of_h === count($months)): ?>
            <td class="table-head text-right"><?php echo number_format($totAmntToPay, 2); ?></td>
            <td class="table-head text-right"><?php echo number_format($totCollection, 2); ?></td>
            <td class="table-head text-right"><?php echo number_format($totBalance, 2); ?></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this question belongs to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is it though? Seems more like performance issue. Granted there's no area in particular that he's asking specifically in the question. As far as I'm concerned the question is valid but not very well asked.

Comment: Please rewrite the question according to this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You've currently posted _a lot_ of code that's not directly relevant to the question. Don't expect us to go through it all and try and guess where the code you're asking about is located.

Comment: Ok i edit it in a simplest way and minimal code of presentation

Comment: It was a perfomance issue.. i just want to know is there any best approach on this? thank you all for responded